# How do I implement Android native code that includes "this" and "MainActivity.this". Using import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;

Tags: codenameone

I am implementing the native android code below to call for biometric authentication with device pin/pattern/password as a backup. I've used the below code in android studio and it works with emulators and physical devices. Essentially the prompt appears when the app launches and also if a button is pressed.

```
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
    
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Executor executor;
    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(MainActivity.this,
                executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                              @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Authentication error: " + errString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Authentication succeeded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
                .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK | androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG | androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)

                .build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);

        // Prompt appears when user clicks "Log in".
        // Consider integrating with the keystore to unlock cryptographic operations,
        // if needed by your app.
        Button biometricLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.b_launchAuth);
        biometricLoginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Log.d("b_launchAuth", "Pressed - Enter");
            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
            Log.d("b_launchAuth", "Pressed - Exit");
        });

    }
}
```

The above code requires adding a build hint: - "android.gradleDep=implementation("androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0")"

The code above refers to "this" (as context:) and MainActivity.this (as activity:). I have imported com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil and tried to replace "this" with AndroidNativeUtil.getContext() and "MainActivity.this" with AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity() however i cannot build successfully.

if I comment out all except: -

```
executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity());
```

or

```
executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(AndroidNativeUtil.getContext());
```

then I can build successfully. My issue seems to be with MainActivity.this.

My current cn1 MyNativeImpl.java code is below: -

```
package com.jamesco.maventestnew;

import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;

public class MyNativeImpl {

    private Executor executor;
    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean nativeAuth(){

        boolean AuthOK = false;

       
        executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(AndroidNativeUtil.getContext());
        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(),
                executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                              @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                //Do nothing for now

            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                AuthOK = true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed();

            }
        });


        promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
                .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK | androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG | androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
                .build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);

        return AuthOK;

    }

}
```

[Here](https://cloud.codenameone.com/build/downloadResult?i=75f59afa-422f-4918-a686-9f0a4cd989b9&b=dcbe2463-4c5f-4a95-ae38-ca67bff6be4c&n=error.txt) is a Link to error log as requested

Comment: What's the compilation error when you add these two lines? Looking at the code if that's the only change this should work. I will need to see the full error log to give an answer.

Comment: I've edited my question to add a link to an error log that is created when the build fails.

Comment: You can also try to generate android archive (aar) library with these android native codes in android studio. Then use it as aar in Codename One

Answer (score 0):

The error from the log you sent in the chat is:

```
MyNativeImpl.java:78: error: no suitable constructor found for BiometricPrompt(Activity,Executor,<anonymous AuthenticationCallback>)
        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(),
                          ^
    constructor BiometricPrompt.BiometricPrompt(FragmentActivity,Executor,AuthenticationCallback) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Activity cannot be converted to FragmentActivity)
    constructor BiometricPrompt.BiometricPrompt(Fragment,Executor,AuthenticationCallback) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Activity cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

The problem is that the [biometrics code](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt) assumes a `Fragment` or a `FragmentActivity`.

I haven't worked with fragments in the past so I'm just guessing here but I think something like this might workaround this specific issue:

```
public class BiometricFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true); 

        // write the biometric code here...
    }
}
```

You can launch that from the native code using this untested code...:

```
BiometricFragment biometricFragment = new BiometricFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(biometricFragment, "biometric_fragment")
                .commit();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am struggling to understand what you are asking me to do. Where do I add this code for instance. Maybe a step1, step 2... etc could be helpful. I try and use the chat option in cn1 but do not receive any response. Not to complain but any question on here takes a day for me to get a response which is not your fault but surely using the chat should overcome this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really sure how to implement this as I never did it. These are educated guesses on the direction that should be taken. Where I wrote "biometric code here" you should write the stuff that you placed previously in the activity as `this` would now be a fragment. This would be a separate class you would now create. The bottom snippet you can use in the Android native code (on the Android main thread) to launch the code. This should trigger the biometric prompt. But again, I'm guessing...

Comment: Thanks Shai. I'll hopefully update my answer with a working method.