# Build Errors when implementing native code

Tags: codenameone

for background this is a continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536541/how-do-i-implement-android-native-code-that-includes-this-and-mainactivity-th) previous question where it was recommended to take the below approach.

I am implementing the native android code below to call for biometric authentication with device pin/pattern/password as a backup. I've used the below code in android studio and it works with emulators and physical devices. Essentially the device authentication is launched when the app launches.

MainActivity: -

```
package com.example.deviceauthentication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BiometricFragment biometricFragment = BiometricFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerId, biometricFragment, "biometric_fragment")
                .commit();


    }
}
```

BiometricFragment class: -

```
package com.example.deviceauthentication;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;


public class BiometricFragment extends Fragment {

    private Executor executor;
    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;


    // Default constructor
    public BiometricFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // Factory method to create a new instance of the fragment
    public static BiometricFragment newInstance() {
        return new BiometricFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        startBiometricAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            executor = getActivity().getMainExecutor();
        }
    }

    // Method to start the biometric authentication process
    public void startBiometricAuthentication() {
        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(this, executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                Log.e("BiometricFragment", "Authentication error: " + errString);
                Log.d("CALLBACK", "*****************False******************");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                Log.d("BiometricFragment", "Authentication succeeded 2");
                Log.d("CALLBACK", "*****************True******************");
                // Authentication succeeded, you can perform further actions here
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                Log.e("BiometricFragment", "Authentication failed");
                Log.d("CALLBACK", "*****************False******************");
            }
        });

        promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric Authentication")
                .setSubtitle("Authenticate using your biometric data")
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK | BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG | BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
                .build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
    }
}
```

I see 4 build errors: -

```
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.

/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:28: error: cannot find symbol/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:28: error: cannot find symbol

                .add(R.id.containerId, biometricFragment, "biometric_fragment")                .add(R.id.containerId, biometricFragment, "biometric_fragment")

                         ^                         ^

  symbol:   variable containerId  symbol:   variable containerId

  location: class id  location: class id

/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:27: error: cannot find symbol/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:27: error: cannot find symbol

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

        ^        ^

  symbol:   method getSupportFragmentManager()  symbol:   method getSupportFragmentManager()

  location: class MyNativeImpl  location: class MyNativeImpl

/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:59: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:59: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

            return new BiometricFragment();            return new BiometricFragment();

                   ^                   ^

/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:58: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class MyNativeImpl.BiometricFragment/tmp/build3217451114737202177xxx/MavenTestNew/src/main/java/com/jamesco/maventestnew/MyNativeImpl.java:58: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class MyNativeImpl.BiometricFragment

        public static BiometricFragment newInstance() {        public static BiometricFragment newInstance() {

                                        ^                                        ^

  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

4 errors4 errors

Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac in MavenTestNew FinishedTask :compileDebugJavaWithJavac in MavenTestNew Finished



> Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac> Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED FAILED

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 5.852 secs.:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 5.852 secs.

AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #0: shutdownAAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #0: shutdown

AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #1: shutdownAAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #1: shutdown

AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #2: shutdownAAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #2: shutdown

AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #3: shutdownAAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #3: shutdown



FAILURE: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.Build failed with an exception.
```

MyNative.java

```
package com.jamesco.maventestnew;

import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

public interface MyNative extends NativeInterface {

    String helloWorld(String hi);
    boolean nativeAuth();

    public class BiometricFragment{}

}
```

MyNativeImpl.java

```
package com.jamesco.maventestnew;

import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MyNativeImpl {

    public boolean nativeAuth(){

        BiometricFragment biometricFragment = BiometricFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerId, biometricFragment, "biometric_fragment")
                .commit();

        boolean AuthOK = false; //ignore this

        return AuthOK; //ignore this

    }

    public class BiometricFragment extends Fragment {

        private Executor executor;
        private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
        private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;


        // Default constructor
        public BiometricFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        // Factory method to create a new instance of the fragment
        public static BiometricFragment newInstance() {
            return new BiometricFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            startBiometricAuthentication();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // You can initialize variables or perform other setup here
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                executor = getActivity().getMainExecutor();
            }
        }

        // Method to start the biometric authentication process
        public void startBiometricAuthentication() {
            biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(this, executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                    Log.e("BiometricFragment", "Authentication error: " + errString);
                    Log.d("AUTHENTICATION", "*****************False******************");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                    Log.d("BiometricFragment", "Authentication succeeded 2");
                    Log.d("AUTHENTICATION", "*****************True******************");
                    // Authentication succeeded, you can perform further actions here
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                    Log.e("BiometricFragment", "Authentication failed");
                    Log.d("AUTHENTICATION", "*****************False******************");
                }
            });

            promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                    .setTitle("Biometric Authentication")
                    .setSubtitle("Authenticate using your biometric data")
                    .setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK | BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG | BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
                    .build();

            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
        }
    }

    public String helloWorld(String param) {
        Log.d("MyNewApp", param);
        return "Tada Android";
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I need to specify the container view ID where the fragment should be placed which explains the first error. How can I overcome this? Also, help with the other errors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I had code there that referred to the `R` class that I copied. This won't work for a standard Codename One class as it requires the XML layout code. A better way to do that is to construct the fragment from code:

```
public class JavaFragment extends Fragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a LinearLayout
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Add a TextView
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView.setText("Fragment created entirely in Java!");
        layout.addView(textView);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

This will create a Fragment component you can work with.

**IMPORTANT:** I suggest sending a build with the bad code commented out and use the generated project source code inside Android Studio. This will give you code completion and check that compilation works. It will save you from the cycle of sending a build to test. Once you get this to compile and run you can just copy the native code back to Codename One.

Comment: Hi Shai. Thank you for the response. Can you elaborate on "This will create a Fragment component you can work with". What is the approach? I'm guessing you mean add the startBiometricAuthentication() code here? How do I launch this from the native nativeAuth() in MyNativeImpl?

Comment: The Android API historically was built on top of `Activity` this was pretty bad design so they later added an incompatible `Fragment` concept which somehow made it worse. They are incompatible with one another and make no sense whatsoever. For some reason the biometric API you have expects a fragment and not an activity. You can create a Fragment component like this and build the UI for it. I wish I could be more help but I haven't worked with Fragments at all so this is outside my domain of expertise.

Comment: Are you suggesting I create a blank fragment, launch it, then call the biometric authentication api from that point? I don't need to make any UI I am tying to use the native authentication. Sorry if I am not understanding you correctly.

Comment: My idea would be to replace the current activity with the fragment above (including added biometric code). once done request authentication via startBiometricAuthentication()

Comment: I think that might work but as I said before. I'm just guessing. I'm not sure this will even compile properly.

Comment: How do I get R.id.containerId for the current activity?

Comment: This is problematic in Codename One. Normally you can do everything you want without the `R` class in Java. But some APIs try and force it really hard. In that case the only solution is wrapping your code in an AAR which is sometimes the path of least resistance.